# Finding alternating sum in python

Tags: python, indexing

i'm trying to write a code finding the alternating sum (for example, for 45678 ---> 4-5+6-7+8) of a certain amount of digits(d) in a long number, and finding which sum is the biggest.
my idea was to split the string so each object in the list will be in the length d, and for each object, substract the digit in index[1] from the digit in index[0], doing it again until index[d-2] and index[d-1] while summing up the results each time, and then swap it with the list object so I'll be able to compare their sizes at the end.

I've gotten this far:

```
def altsum_digits(n,d):
    sum = 0
    my_num = "n"
    list_lend = [my_num[x:x+d] for x in range(0, len(my_num),d)]

    pos = 0
    total = 0

    for i in list_lend:

        total = int(i[pos])- int(i[pos+1])
        pos = pos + 2
```

but I keep getting errors like invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'n', or index out of range...

thanks for any kind of help, I'm just a beginner so be gentle [:

Comment: Do you mean `my_num = n`?!

Comment: Please fix your indentation errors so the code can actually run and demonstrate the bugs you're trying to get fixed, if you want people to fix those bugs. Also, using a haphazard mix of 1, 2, and 4 spaces for indentation makes you code hard to read; stick to 4 everywhere, and get yourself an editor that makes indentation easier.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider breaking this down into simpler functions. For example, first write a function that returns a complete alternating sum for a complete string, and get that working. Then you can write a function that just gets each group of `d` digits in a larger string. Then put them together into a function that gets each group of digits and gets their alternating sums, and finds the max.

Comment: I mean my_num = "n", because I want to split the num as a string using a list.

Comment: and I changed the indentation I hope this is ok now [:

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
def altsum( n ):
   # convert n to a string
   s = str( n )
   # build a tuple with all the even index entries converted to int
   evn = map( int, tuple( s[0::2] ))
   # build a tuple with all the odd index entries converted to int
   odd = map( int, tuple( s[1::2] ))
   # compute the cumulative sum for both tuples and return the difference
   return sum( evn ) - sum( odd )
```

Ex.: for `n` = 45678

- `evn` <- `( 4, 6, 8 )`
- `odd` <- `( 5, 7 )`

`sum( evn ) - sum( odd )` = `( 18 - 12 )` = `6`